# Django login_required decorator not working properly

Tags: django-views

I am doing a panchayath solid waste management project in django. What I want to do is, only allow Admin to add Panchayath member only if they are logged in. And I gave login_required decorator and its working fine ie when I visit the AddMember view without login in, it is getting redirected. But problem is when Admin log in and goes to AddMember view, it is also redirecting to login page. So anyone explain me the correct working of login_required??

Comment: If that is causing you some error maybe you can try using ```if request.user.is_authenticated``` inside the view then show him the ```AddMember view``` or else redirect him to ```login```

Comment: I am not getting any errror bro, redirecting after login and adding members